# Sending a private message to another user?

Tags: discussion, support, users

Since I don't have the enough reputation to "add a comment" (less than 50), I was surprised that I can't find the way to send a private message to another user.

How can I do that?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1607/how-to-contact-other-user and http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1250/how-to-contact-a-user